# What is the term for the class of service that provides network file-browser file access?

Tags: samba

SSH enables remote (WAN / LAN) viewing files through a terminal.

As I understand it, SAMBA:

1. provides access through a file-browser (Nautilus / Finder)
2. requires the user to be on the same LAN as the SAMBA server

What is the **class name** of *file-access service*, that support networked file browsers (Nautilus, Safari, etc.)?

I would like to Google this class so that I can evaluate options that will provide WAN file browser access.

Edits to the OP / clarifying questions are appreciated.